# Google Login in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, google-signin

Is there a way to implement Google Login without Firebase?

I just want to get a valid token to pass it to the Server, to use my own strategy, but I don't want to be dependet on Firebase. But I only find Google Login tutorials using Firebase.

Comment: I only found this library on github.. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus you can try this for your app.

Comment: Firebase is required in your posted tutorial!

Comment: I guess there is no other method . Better to stick on the Google plus plugin . Note: Follow step by step guide mentioned in the tutorial ,else you will not get the correct response